# Existe diferença entre um compilador e um interpretador?

Tags: javascript, c, compiladores, interpretador, jit

Qual é a grande diferença entre um compilador e um interpretador?

Em linguagens como C, Java é usado um compilador, já em JavaScript por exemplo é usado um interpretador, porém fui confrontado com o termo JIT (just in time compiler).

Como poderei classificar o processamento do JavaScript neste caso específico?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linguagens dificilmente estão ligadas ao uso de um [compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101), [interpretador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190209/101) ou [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101). [Implementações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) sim. [Diferença entre linguagem e compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). Um [exemplo de linguagem tida como compilada, mas possui interpretador é C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179754/101).

Hoje os navegadores e a maioria dos outros usos do JavaScript de fato usam um JITter para obter mais performance, mas não é algo inerente ao JS. É comum as pessoas classificarem o processo de JITting como uma interpretação. De fato, o caso do JS isso ocorre mesmo porque ele tem que ler o fonte para gerar o código nativo, em outros casos ele pode ler apenas uma representação intermediária. A interpretação ocorre uma vez apenas, diferente da interpretação tradicional, então é como uma compilação sob demanda e não uma interpretação clássica.

No passado o JS era totalmente interpretado e ainda existem implementações assim, apesar de praticamente consideradas obsoletas.

No futuro é *possível* que o JS seja **compilado** para [WebAssembly](http://webassembly.org/), assim como outras linguagens poderão ser usadas.

[Veja também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22647/101). E [diferenças](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No caso do javascript no front-end, o V8 do chrome ou spidermonkey do moziila são JIT @bigown?

Comment: @LucasCosta Sim.