# Linguagem de script sempre é construída sobre outra linguagem?

Tags: característica-linguagem, design-de-linguagem

Estava lendo mais sobre o que caracteriza uma linguagem de *script*. A saber:

[O que é uma linguagem de script?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17082/5878)

E a própria pergunta cita as linguagens que eu conheço de *script* PHP, Python e Ruby, sendo, possivelmente, as mais conhecidas no geral. A definição do que é uma linguagem de *script* parece não ser muito bem definida, mas das três citadas, sei que o PHP e o Python são construídas sobre a linguagem C e do Ruby, que não tenho tanto conhecimento, achei a frase "A implementação 1.8.7 padrão é escrita em C" ([Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))).

- Repositório oficial da linguagem PHP: https://github.com/php/php-src
- Repositório oficial da linguagem Python: https://github.com/python/cpython
- Repositório oficial da linguagem Ruby: https://github.com/ruby/ruby

Então, todas as linguagens ditas de *script* são desenvolvidas sobre outra linguagem ou isso é uma particularidade das linguagens citadas? Existe algum motivo claro para se desenvolver uma linguagem sobre outra linguagem?

Comment: Defina "'construída sobre outra linguagem" :) Isso é importante, eu acho que você até sabe disso.

Comment: @bigown serem implementadas em outra linguagem, como as três citadas serem em C. Não sei se eu fiz confusão e acabei deixando passar um detalhe simples que responderia a dúvida.

Comment: Eu vou responder porque é mais complicado que isso.

Comment: Creio que sua pergunta tem haver com "Linguagem de programação de alto nível" e "Linguagem de programação de baixo nível".

Comment: Eu acho que tem uma pergunta idêntica no SO, se eu achar eu melhoro a minha :)

Comment: `PyPy` é o interpretador Python escrito em Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vou começar lançando alguns *links* importantes para entender sobre linguagens, compiladores, interpretadores, etc.:

- [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101)
- [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101)
- [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101)
- [Existe diferença entre um compilador e um interpretador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190209/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre linguagem compilada para linguagem interpretada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101)
- [Especificação e Implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101)

Linguagens são **especificações**, então elas existem por si só, elas existem "no papel". Em geral a forma como elas serão implementadas não importa.

Compiladores ou interpretadores são **implementados** sempre em alguma linguagem, seja código de máquina, Assembly, C, ou outra linguagem, não importa.

## *Runtime*

É comum as linguagens terem uma biblioteca padrão que pode ser escrita na própria linguagem, em outra mais adequada, possivelmente mais rápida, ou um híbrido disto. Também haverá um *runtime* que pode ser absurdamente simples como em C (ou nem existente como Assembly), ou monstruosamente grande como Java, C#, e outros, além, claro das linguagens interpretadas ou que rodam em máquinas virtuais.

"Linguagens interpretadas" precisam de um *runtime* que faça a interpretação. "Linguagens compiladas" que geram um [*bytecode*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) também precisam de um interpretador desse *bytecode*. [Linguagens JITtadas como JS ou Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22647/101), ([C# também pode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125588/101), mas existe variação nativa) precisam do [JITTer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101). Note que falo de linguagens, mas no fundo são suas implementações.

Esse *runtime* precisa ser escrito em alguma linguagem. Pelo menos uma parte dele precisa ser feito em outra linguagem para dar o *bootstrap*. Em geral um *bootstrap* precisa ser feito em Assembly e/ou C para ser muito simples e acessar o mais baixo nível.

Tem casos que precisam de uma máquina virtual para rodar isso e outras coisas necessárias para a infraestrutura da linguagem. Não deixa de fazer parte do *runtime*.

Linguagens de tipagem dinâmicas precisam de uma infra de acesso à memória e tratamento dos problemas em tempo de execução, isso exige algo em *runtime* que deve ser escrito em alguma linguagem que entenda a memória de forma direta, não pode ser uma linguagem muito abstrata. C é muito adequada para isso.

Muitas linguagens hoje em dia trabalham com memória gerenciada que foi um dos maiores *boosts* de produtividade da programação depois do advento da linguagem de alto nível e a modularização de código. Absurdamente mais que OOP que muitos acham que é a 8a. maravilha da natureza :) Isso tem um custo que muitas linguagens secundárias não podem pagar.

## Linguagens de *script*

Vamos combinar que linguagens de *script* são interpretadas ou rodam em uma máquina virtual, possuem tipagem dinâmica, memória gerenciada e não costumam ter o máximo da performance por conta própria.

Então para fazer esse *runtime* precisa de outra linguagem mais poderosa, flexível e rápida. Seja para interpretar, gerenciar a memória ou executar outras tarefas. Uma parte dele até pode ser escrito na própria linguagem, mas seria terrível. Uma parte não tem jeito, precisa de algo diferente. Até C precisa de um tiquinho de outra linguagem (Assembly).

O compilador dá para escrever nela própria, mas certamente será muito pouco adequada. O interpretador não dá 100%, embora eu imagine uma gambiarra que dê uma parte, mas não faz o menor sentido.

Até por performance, boa parte da biblioteca padrão de uma linguagem de *script* costuma ser escrita em C ou C++.

Algumas linguagens podem ser de *script* apenas em certa implementação. Isso muda um pouco, são linguagens que originalmente não foram idealizadas para serem de *script*, mas foram implementadas assim, aí dá para implementar quase 100% nela mesma, mas só porque ela não possui todas essas características. É o [caso de C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179754/101) que só precisa de um *bootstrap* minúsculo em Assembly.

## Implementações

Várias linguagens possuem diversas implementações, embora só uma costuma ser oficial e até por isso seja a mais popular. É verdade que as secundárias costumam ser de qualidade inferior, recebem menos amor e de fato muitas são experimentos.

[Lua tem diversas implementações](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaImplementations), tem até VM escrita nela mesmo. O que não quer dizer que sejam adequadas.

[Python também tem](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations), com destaque ao PyPy que é escrito em Python mesmo.

[O mesmo vale para JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines).

[Ruby também está disponível alternativamente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Alternate_implementations), mas não sei se alguma foi escrita em Ruby.

Certamente ocorre com outras linguagens.

## Conclusão

Então nenhuma linguagem é tão autossuficiente assim, exceto o Assembly. Mas se a dúvida é sobre tudo isso que eu falei acima, sim, linguagem de *script* sempre é construída em cima de outra linguagem, seja em parte, seja o todo.

Performance é o principal motivo por optar por outra linguagem para escrever quase 100% de uma **implementação** para uma linguagem de *script*.

Vou contribuir com outros repositórios:

- [Lua](https://github.com/lua/lua)
- [Harbour](https://github.com/harbour/core)
- [JavaScript](https://github.com/v8/v8) (a mais usada implementação)
- [Perl](https://github.com/Perl/perl5).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Resumindo, a linguagem em si é, basicamente, um texto estruturado que será analisado pelo compilador/interpretador. O compilador/interpretador que é, de fato, escrito em outra linguagem. De forma sucinta seria isso?

Comment: Isso, mas o compilador é o de menos. O *runtime* é muito mais importante. Tanto que o compilador frequentemente é escrito 100% na própria linguagem, exceto as linguagens de *script* :) Vou achar *script language* que tem seu compilador escrito na própria linguagem, mais como experimento do que uso real.

Comment: `PyPy`? Seria isso que você está atrás?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Eu ia por mesmo, depois esqueci, já já edito, obrigado por lembrar.

Comment: @bigown às ordens