# Como fazer uma "compilação" do código em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilação

Sabendo que Python é uma linguagem interpretada, existe alguma forma de compilar o programa em Python? Com isso quero dizer, como verificar os erro de sintaxe sem ter que esperar tal parte do programa ocorrer para a verificação.
Pois os erros só são mostrados em terminal ou IDE em tempo de execução.

Comment: Obs: Erros de sintaxe aparecem sim na IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode só gerar o *bytecode* através dos módulos [`py_compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html) e [`compileall`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/compileall.html). Para usá-lo precisa usar a [opção `-m`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html):

```
python -m py_compile arquivo.py
```

Comment: Estas são alternativas, não necessariamente para gerar o *bytecode*. O que ele quer é só compilar, e isto resolve.

Comment: sim resolve, pois assim posso verificar erros antes da execução e é isso que preciso. Obrigado