# Diferença entre compilação Ahead-Of-Time e Just-in-Time

Tags: compilação, compiladores, jit

Enquanto estava lendo sobre *templates* para ASP.NET eu vi que um tinha suporte ao AOT (Ahead of Time) e o outro não falava nada.

Estive pesquisando sobre o assunto e não consegui entender muito bem a diferença e definição *Ahead of Time* e *Just in Time* na questão de compilação por não entender perfeitamente o processo.

Como funcionam realmente os dois citados acima? Poderiam me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O compilador AOT é a mais tradicional onde você desenvolve, nele você invoca o [compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101) e ele faz todo o processo culminando no executável que poderá ser chamado na hora ou transportado para outro local. Normalmente ele não precisa ser tão rápido e pode fazer otimizações mais extremas.

O compilador JIT é invocado no momento da execução, portanto em cada chamada do executável há um processo de compilação. É comum que tenha um processo de compilação anterior que já garante que algumas coisas estão corretas e mantém um formato mais fácil de manipulação. Como ele será executado todas as vezes é importante que o processo seja rápido. Por isso é comum que ele não seja bom em fazer otimizações, a não ser os mais sofisticados que detectam que algo é executado muitas vezes (*hot path*) e compense fazer um processo de otimização maior, e aí ele pode até dar um resultado melhor por já ter mais informação sobre o ambiente de execução e contexto atual (chama-se *tiering*). Pode ser visto mais em [O que é um JITter?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101).

De uma certa forma podemos dizer que os interpretadores sejam JITters, apesar do termo não costumar ser usado, me parece até mais adequado que "interpretador", pelo menos na maioria das implementações atuais.

Os JITters mais conhecidos são do Java e C#, ambos possuem um processo de compilação anterior antes. Se considerarmos a interpretação podemos falar em quase todas implementações do JavaScript (PHP terá). Outras linguagens que costumam ser consideradas interpretadas podem ter um processo de JITter mais clássico. Os AOTs mais conhecidos são do C e C++, além do Delphi, Go, D, Rust. Mas note que todas essas linguagens podem e costumam ter as duas formas. Uma não impede a outra a não ser que a linguagem tenha especificado diferente por alguma razão, mas isso não costuma acontecer.

Quando é comum o uso do JITter e a tecnologia permite o AOT pode dar um ganho na carga de execução, e isso pode ser muito importante onde tem muitas chamadas ao executável e precisa responder rápido.

No caso de *templates* pode se referir apenas ao fato do gabarito virar um código que monta as *strings* de forma direta sem precisar interpretar o código do gabarito. Eu não chamaria exatamente de compilação JIT ou AOT nesse caso, apesar de ser algo parecido, eu diria que isso é só uma geração de código.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Por que o C e C++ são considerados AOT e o C# por exemplo não, já que há um processo de compilação anterior a execução de suas aplicações?

Comment: Porque em C e C++ só tem esse processo anterior, não tem um posterior antes da execução.