# Quando usar uma linguagem de script?

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, lua, script

Quando usar uma linguagem de *script* e qual o cenário ideal para o uso dela?

Tenho lido a respeito de linguagens de *script* e pensei na possibilidade de usá-las em meu projeto C/C++ para servidor de um jogo, o que me leva a outra questão: Sei que depende muito da linguagem escolhida, mas suponhamos que eu use LuaJIT. Perderei muito em desempenho?

Acredito estar um tanto paranoico, pensando somente no desempenho do aplicativo e o quão rápido ele deve ser.

Comment: Sobre linguagens interpretadas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22650/53279

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza Sobre o que é uma linguagem de script, eu já li. Gostaria de saber quando é o momento mais apropriado para o uso delas e sobre a perda de desempenho. Não sou inteligente ao ponto de entender a maneira que todos os programadores falam, por isso estou pedindo algo mais simples de se entender, pois sou bem burrinho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso não dá para responder assim e, sim, está um pouco "paranoico" com performance. Ela deve ser analisada, deve haver critérios, mas a preocupação deve ser no caso real.

O que mais dá performance é o algoritmo correto. A escolha da linguagem vai até certo ponto, é óbvio que uma linguagem de *script* nunca chegará nem perto de uma linguagem de baixo nível, mas também não é para ser tão trágico assim. Dependendo do que for fazer, na prática não faz muita diferença.

Não é tão fácil acontecer, mas se fizer algo simples em Lua e tentar fazer o mesmo em C e se enrolar, C pode ficar mais lento. C tem inúmeras oportunidades de otimização, mas também tem um número tão grande de fazer besteira.

[LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/) tem desempenho impressionante já que executa código nativamente, igual C faria, na maior parte dos casos. Mas não consegue se comparar com C que permite várias otimizações que são impossíveis para Lua. É bem verdade que LuaJIT pode fazer algumas em tempo de execução que C não consegue por já ter sido compilado. Já deve ter lido o site do produto de forma profunda, se não o fez, ainda não deveria optar por ele.

Mesmo Lua "pura" ainda tem um desempenho surpreendente para uma linguagem de *script*, que pode até mesmo ser previamente compilada para um *bytecode*.

Enfim, não existe resposta absoluta para isto, só tendo experiência prévia ou experimentando.

[Dá para brincar de ver performance de cada linguagem.](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/) Mas cuidado! Isso é mais uma brincadeira do que algo para considerar seriamente. É alguma referência, mas não uma verdade absoluta. Tem um monte de fatores que podem dar resultados enganadores.

Se souber onde aplicar o *script* e onde precisa do máximo de performance, pode ser um ganha-ganha. Por outro lado, pode ser que não precise de *script* para nada.

O cenário ideal é para quando precisar de personalização facilitada, possivelmente por terceiros. O *script* tende te dar mais velocidade de desenvolvimento, cobrando o preço do desempenho da aplicação.

Não sei se te ajuda, mas [tem mais informações no GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/2914/2217).

Comment: Ajudou demais! Eu sempre fico me dizendo que se o aplicativo não tiver um bom desempenho, ele não vai prestar, mas com sua resposta, posso ver o quanto estou enganado em relação a isso. Quanto a quando usar, você me esclareceu bem o ponto que eu toquei. Acho que vale a pena usar em meu projeto. Gostaria de te reputar, mas infelizmente, ainda não consigo. Muito obrigado pela sua resposta.