# Quais os Prós e contras das linguagens de script?

Tags: script

Estive pesquisando e puder ver o desenvolvimento e abstração que as linguagem de programação vêm tomando. Quais são os reais prós e contras das linguagens de script em relação às compiladas, já que, Ruby, Python e tantas outras vem ganhando espaço em importantíssimas áreas como Machine Learning, Big Data, e IA?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17082/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216217/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170075/101

Comment: A resposta à última questão que o Maniero colocou como relacionada elucida muitas coisas. Como quem já trabalhou dando suporte ao CENAPAD-UFC, posso dizer que linguagens de script permitem expressar mais coisas escrevendo menos. Nesse sentido, elas são usadas como "linguagem de colagem", com o núcleo pesado do processamento sendo feito em C ou em Fortran.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Ajudou. :D