# Problema em Python

Tags: python

Olá, recebi este problema para resolver em python mas não conheço muito da linguagem, conheço C, mas acredito que meu problema está na leitura do problema, recebi o programa assim sem mais nenhuma explicação e quem sabe alguém possa me ajudar.

```
        #!/bin/env python3
        # coding: utf-8

        def dormir(dia_semana, feriado):
            """
            dia_semana é True para dias na semana
            feriado é True nos feriados
            você pode ficar dormindo quando é feriado ou não é dia semana
            retorne True ou False conforme você vá dormir ou não
            """

        def alunos_problema(a_sorri, b_sorri):
            """
            temos dois alunos a e b
            a_sorri e b_sorri indicam se a e b sorriem
            temos problemas quando ambos estão sorrindo ou ambos não estão sorrindo
            retorne True quando houver problemas
            """

        def soma_dobro(a, b):
            """
            dados dois números inteiros retorna sua soma
            porém se os números forem iguais retorna o dobro da soma
            soma_dobro(1, 2) -> 3
            soma_dobro(2, 2) -> 8
            """

        def diff21(n):
            """
            dado um inteiro n retorna a diferença absoluta entre n e 21
            porém se o número for maior que 21 retorna o dobro da diferença absoluta
            diff21(19) -> 2
            diff21(25) -> 8
            dica: abs(x) retorna o valor absoluto de x
            """

        def papagaio(falando, hora):
            """
            temos um papagaio que fala alto
            hora é um parâmetro entre 0 e 23
            temos problemas se o papagaio estiver falando antes da 7 ou depois das 20
            """

        def dez(a, b):
            """
            dados dois inteiros a e b
            retorna True se um dos dois é 10 ou a soma é 10
            """

        def dista10(n):
            """
            seja um inteiro n
            retorna True se a diferença absoluta entre n e 100 ou n e 200
            for menor ou igual a 10
            dista10(93) -> True
            dista10(90) -> True
            dista10(89) -> False
            """

        def apaga(s, n):
            """
            seja uma string s e um inteiro n
            retorna uma nova string sem a posição n
            apaga('kitten', 1) -> 'ktten'
            apaga('kitten', 4) -> 'kittn'
            """

        def troca(s):
            """
            seja uma string s
            se s tiver tamanho <= 1 retorna ela mesma
            caso contrário troca a primeira e última letra
            troca('code') -> 'eodc'
            troca('a') -> 'a'
            troca('ab') -> 'ba'
            """

        # Área de testes: só mexa aqui se souber o que está fazendo!
        acertos = 0
        total = 0 

        def test(obtido, esperado):
            global acertos, total
            total += 1
            if obtido != esperado:
                prefixo = ' Falhou.'
            else:
                prefixo = ' Passou.'
                acertos += 1
            print ('%s Esperado: %s \tObtido: %s' % (prefixo,repr(esperado), 
                repr(obtido)))

        def main():
          print ('Oba! Hoje vou ficar dormindo!')
          test(dormir(False, False), True)
          test(dormir(True, False), False)
          test(dormir(False, True), True)
          test(dormir(True, True), True)

          print ()
          print ('Alunos problema')
          test(alunos_problema(True, True), True)
          test(alunos_problema(False, False), True)
          test(alunos_problema(True, False), False)
          test(alunos_problema(False, True), False)

          print ()
          print ('Soma dobro')
          test(soma_dobro(1, 2), 3)
          test(soma_dobro(3, 2), 5)
          test(soma_dobro(2, 2), 8)
          test(soma_dobro(-1, 0), -1)
          test(soma_dobro(0, 0), 0)
          test(soma_dobro(0, 1), 1)

          print ()
          print ('Diff21')
          test(diff21(19), 2)
          test(diff21(10), 11)
          test(diff21(21), 0)
          test(diff21(22), 2)
          test(diff21(25), 8)
          test(diff21(30), 18)

          print ()
          print ('Papagaio')
          test(papagaio(True, 6), True)
          test(papagaio(True, 7), False)
          test(papagaio(False, 6), False)
          test(papagaio(True, 21), True)
          test(papagaio(False, 21), False)
          test(papagaio(True, 23), True)
          test(papagaio(True, 20), False)

          print ()
          print ('Dez')
          test(dez(9, 10), True)
          test(dez(9, 9), False)
          test(dez(1, 9), True)
          test(dez(10, 1), True)
          test(dez(10, 10), True)
          test(dez(8, 2), True)
          test(dez(8, 3), False)
          test(dez(10, 42), True)
          test(dez(12, -2), True)

          print ()
          print ('Dista 10')
          test(dista10(93), True)
          test(dista10(90), True)
          test(dista10(89), False)
          test(dista10(110), True)
          test(dista10(111), False)
          test(dista10(121), False)
          test(dista10(0), False)
          test(dista10(5), False)
          test(dista10(191), True)
          test(dista10(189), False)
          test(dista10(190), True)
          test(dista10(200), True)
          test(dista10(210), True)
          test(dista10(211), False)
          test(dista10(290), False)

          print ()
          print ('Apaga')
          test(apaga('kitten', 1), 'ktten')
          test(apaga('kitten', 0), 'itten') 
          test(apaga('kitten', 2), 'kiten') 
          test(apaga('kitten', 4), 'kittn')
          test(apaga('Hi', 0), 'i')
          test(apaga('Hi', 1), 'H')
          test(apaga('code', 0), 'ode')
          test(apaga('code', 1), 'cde')
          test(apaga('code', 2), 'coe')
          test(apaga('code', 3), 'cod')
          test(apaga('chocolate', 8), 'chocolat')

          print ()
          print ('Troca letras')
          test(troca('code'), 'eodc')       
          test(troca('a'), 'a')
          test(troca('ab'), 'ba')
          test(troca('abc'), 'cba')
          test(troca(''), '')
          test(troca('Chocolate'), 'ehocolatC')
          test(troca('nythoP'), 'Python')
          test(troca('hello'), 'oellh')



        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
            print("\n%d Testes, %d Ok, %d Falhas: Nota %.1f" %(total, acertos,
             total-acertos, float(acertos*10)/total))
            if total == acertos:
                print("Parabéns, seu programa rodou sem falhas!")
```

Lembrete, não preciso da resolução do problema, apenas de um guia.

Comment: Eu tenho a impressão de que o seu problema é justamente implementar o que está descrito em cada uma das funçõese manter os testes para verificar se os mesmos estão corretos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é um arquivo python executável (no sentido de que ele pode ser executado. Obviamente, ele é um arquivo fonte. Um [script](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17082/215), se preferir). Se ele está num arquivo chamado `exercicio.py`, você pode chamar ele usando:

```
python exercicio.py
```

Ou (em ambiente *NIX), simplesmente usando:

```
./exercicio.py
```

(Assumindo que o Python 3 esteja presente no sistema, no caminho indicado).

A parte final do arquivo - embaixo de onde está escrito "Área de testes: só mexa aqui se souber o que está fazendo!" - é exatamente o que está dizendo: uma parte do programa que não é para você mexer. Essa parte é responsável por testar as funções definidas no começo do arquivo, essas sim de sua responsabilidade.

Ou seja, no fim das contas tudo o que você precisa fazer é implementar as funções definidas no começo do arquivo, e executá-lo. Se houver algum erro de compilação, o compilador vai avisar, e se houver algum erro de lógica, o teste vai imprimir `Falhou. Esperado: X; Obtido: Y` - de modo que você vai ficar sabendo onde errou, e pode ir lá consertar.

De resto, é aprender a sintaxe e semântica de Python. Algumas dicas pra quem está chegando em Python vindo do C:

- Não precisa remover as strings que descrevem o problema - em Python elas são chamadas "docstrings", e servem pra documentar o que a função faz; escreva seu código logo abaixo delas (respeitando a identação, é claro);
- `True` e `False` escrevem assim mesmo, com iniciais maiúsculas;
- Os operadores booleanos - que em C são `!`, `&&` e `||` - em Python são `not`, `and` e `or`;
- Aritmética normal;
- `return` normal;
- Os `if`, `else`, `while` etc não têm parênteses envolvendo as condições; não existe `for`;
- Não precisa declarar as variáveis antes de usar, nem estabelecer seu tipo;
- Sem `;` no final das instruções;
- Um bloco não se delimita com `{ }`, mas sim com um código identado logo abaixo; use `:` para iniciar um bloco; Ex.:

  ```
  if condição:
      código
  ```
- etc (se você está estudando Python, muito do que eu falei aqui você já sabia)