# Qual é o paradigma de programação usado pelo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

Qual é o paradigma de programação usado pelo JavaScript ou se ela é como o Python que usa múltiplos paradigmas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Hoje qualquer linguagem *mainstream* (que todos conhecem e usam, que possui popularidade) usa [vários paradigmas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129597/101).

O principal de todas elas (só entre as *mainstream*) é o [imperativo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming), JS não é diferente, e até pode ser usada na forma [procedural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) (obviamente de forma [estruturada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming)).

JavaScript é conhecida por também ser [orientada a objeto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) através de [protótipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

Mas como toda linguagem moderna, bebe no paradigma [funcional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) cada vez mais.

Não podemos deixar de notar uma forte influência em programação [orientada a eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80601/4995).

Recentemente a orientação a objeto pode ser expressada através de [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming) também, ainda que de forma apenas sintática. Mesmo assim o uso é um pouco diferente do que encontramos nas linguagens mais conhecidas que se dizem OOP (C++, C#, Java, etc.), até porque a tipagem dinâmica força diferenças. De qualquer forma adota-se um pouco o estilo OO, mas está longe de ser puramente OO, como o é Smalltalk, por exemplo.

A linguagem usa [tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) (por enquanto :P) e é usada como [*script*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17082/101). É dita como [tipagem fraca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), mas isso não ocorre em todas situações, possuindo [tipos primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) (ao contrário do que dizem os comentários abaixo) e dicionários para preencher os protótipos e simular as classes (nativamente na linguagem). Costuma rodar de forma [interpretada, mas no fundo é compilada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101).

A linguagem teve forte influência de [Self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_%28programming_language%29) que é uma linguagem "puramente" orientada a objetos. E [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) que é funcional de forma pragmática. Além das diversas linguagens imperativas existentes.

Entenda [O que é paradigma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: entretanto devemos notar que a orientação a objeto em javascript é muito diferente do conceito "puro" de orientação a objeto que outras linguagens como C++, Java, entre outra têm. Não tente usar os conceitos tradicionais nela que não dá certo. Caso leia inglês, veja aqui minha peleja a esse respeito: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115645/simple-object-oriented-calculator-part-4

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira realmente, tudo no javascript é objeto =)

Comment: O Javascript segue a real implementação de orientação a objetos, a que temos presente em Smaltalk, que não há tipos primitivos. Por isto ele disse que esse OO difere um pouco do mais conhecido(class-based).

Comment: @nbro acho que você precisa entender um pouco melhor o que o paradigma significa. Provavelmente você tem uma visão própria do que é OOP que não coaduna com o que é aceito até mesmo nas diferentes definições aceitas.

Comment: Não há nada que obrigue OOP suportar classes. JS suporta classes, antes do ES6 suportava protótipos que é um mecanismo válido para obter as mesmas funcionalidades de classes, suporta encapsulamento, herança e polimorfismo. Cada um pode ter sua opinião, tem erros no *design* de JS mas no geral é uma das linguagens mais geniais já criadas pelo menos para seu propósito inicial. Eu nem gosto e não costumo usar JS, mas ela é bem melhor do que alguns *blogueiros* gostam de dizer. Em geral pessoas que não entendem de linguagens de programação, que é um domínio complexo.

Comment: Algumas perguntas que podem ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108548/101,