# O que é uma linguagem de multi-paradigmas?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem, independente-de-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

O título da pergunta já resume tudo o que quero saber. O Visual Basic .NET, C#, Boo, C++ são linguagens de multi-paradigmas. O que é um paradigma? E uma linguagem de multi-paradigmas?

Comment: Esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108105/27190) explica o que é paradigma.

Comment: O .NET não é uma linguagem de programação, se não me engano ele é um framework.

Comment: Não disse em nenhuma parte da pergunta que .NET é uma linguagem :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Já respondi o que é paradigma em duas oportunidades: [O que é paradigma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101O) e em [pergunta onde tinha um contexto específico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108105/101).

O termo já responde tudo :P São linguagens que suportam mais de um paradigma com mecanismos específicos.

Acho que dá pra dizer que todas linguagens modernas, populares e de propósito geral são multi paradigmas. Isso é fundamental para a linguagem ter sucesso. Quando a linguagem se propõe a ir além de um nicho específico ela precisa ter várias formas de resolver problemas, porque lidará com problemas variados.

Essencialmente toda linguagem é [imperativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101). Orientação a objeto está na moda e quase toda linguagem o adota. As linguagens não dispensam pelo menos algumas características funcionais e cada dia mais as linguagens vão adicionando mecanismos próprios deste paradigma, isso acontece com C++, Java, C#, Python, etc.

## Paradigmas

Algumas adotam um estilo mais [procedural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195069/101) e [modular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101), ou pelo menos permite o seu uso, mas hoje costuma haver preferência pelo OO, ainda que muitas vezes a diferença seja pequena e questionável (no sentido de que não há consenso do que seja OO) quando está usando um ou outro.

Algumas optam por outros paradigmas auxiliares para atender algumas necessidades mais específicas. Isso ocorre com [eventos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming), [aspectos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), [concorrência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) ou [reflexividade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29), por exemplo. Até poderia colocar [contratos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) também. Há controvérsias se é eles são paradigmas (falo disso no primeiro *link* ali em cima).

Outros paradigmas são necessários para atender sua filosofia básica. Linguagem realmente [tipadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) não existem sem [genericidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming), [meta-programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) ou alguma forma semelhante.

Algumas tem adotado um estilo mais [declarativo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming), que se opõe ao imperativo, pelo menos para algum tipo de tarefa.

A [Wikipedia tem uma comparação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_multi-paradigm_programming_languages). Não é 100% confiável (estou sendo legal), tem subjetividade e a tabela não é bem curada, mas ajuda ter uma ideia.

## Outras informações

As linguagens conseguem pelo menos simular um paradigma com bibliotecas e padrões de uso. Isso por si só não pode classificar a linguagem como multi paradigma.

Algumas linguagens usam o termo destacada e primordialmente como marketing. Algumas vão em direção oposta e optam por atender bem um tipo de problema.

Se pesquisar aqui mesmo ou acompanhar o artigo da Wikipedia (tá cheio de *links* ótimos pelo menos pra introdução) vai saber mais sobre vários outros paradigmas que eu chamaria de auxiliares.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Alguém negativou mas não disse o que está errado. Gostaríamos de saber o que é uma linguagem multi paradigma então.

Comment: Provavelmente alguém que não gosta de você; não vejo nenhum problema na resposta.