# O que faz Python ser uma linguagem de programação multiparadigma?

Tags: python, característica-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

Aqui [nessa página do Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_multiparadigma) cita alguns exemplos de linguagem multiparadigma como C++, Groovy, Oz, Ruby, Scala, Swift, Groovy e inclusive o [Python](https://www.python.org/). Particularmente não achei tão objetiva a explicação.

O que faz Python ser uma linguagem de programação multiparadigma?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ela permite usar [vários paradigmas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129597/101) :P

Sabendo que o [paradigma é só um nome pomposo para o estilo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101), você pode programar em mais de um estilo. Se não tiver certeza absoluta do que é um paradigma e quais os principais, não deixe de ler este último *link*.

Como toda linguagem *mainstream*, Python tem o estilo básico de [programação imperativa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming), que são a maioria do comandos, que controlam o fluxo, atribuição de variáveis, etc.

Ela tem uma influência do [paradigma funcional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), permitindo recursão, uso de *lambda*, compreensões de coleções de dados, etc. É um pouco de exagero dizer que Python é uma linguagem funcional, mas pelo marketing acaba-se usando, todas linguagens o fazem. De fato dá para adotar um pouco o estilo, mas só um pouco, bem pouco.

Além disso ela permite alguns **paradigmas secundários**. A [orientação a objetos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) é o mais claro deles. Como ela permite o uso de classes com encapsulamento, herança e polimorfismo, ela se conforma com OOP (paradigma que está longe de ter a importância que muitos acreditam que ele tem, e isso não é opinião). Mas a organização do código pode seguir o [paradigma procedural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) também, onde apenas funções simples são usadas.

Como a maioria das linguagens dinâmicas (que alguns até consideram paradigma) ela possui [capacidade reflexiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) (informações sobre a estrutura dos seus dados e códigos).

Uma linguagem dita multi paradigma tende a agradar mais pessoas e atende mais necessidades. E de fato tem um fundo de verdade que Python adota alguns estilos extras além do imperativo que é o seu forte.

Não se baseie na [tabela comparativa da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_multi-paradigm_programming_languages), tem muita coisa errada ali. Parece que foi feito por alguém que sequer entende o que sejam os paradigmas (na verdade feito por várias pessoas cada um com um *background* diferente, deve ter dado muita briga, foi algo criado em comitê que não tem consenso).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).