# O que é programação procedural e não procedural?

Tags: terminologia, paradigma-de-programação

Li [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122441/35406), mas sem muitos detalhes, que:

> "[...] a programação procedural é uma evolução da programação
>   estruturada [...]"

E [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108209/35406) também:

> [...] programação procedural é algo que, até certo ponto,
>   inevitável [...]

E [no Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_procedural) fala que:

> [...] às vezes utilizado como sinônimo de programação imperativa [...]

Mas o que realmente é programação procedural e não procedural?

Comment: Relacionada: [Paradigma Imperativo e Declarativo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/91)

Comment: isso e realmente uma duvida minha, não e uma critica, eu vejo diversas perguntas deste tipo que aprecem ser feitas apenas para receber pontos.  se é pra trazer conteúdo, nao existe uma forma de voce mesmo ja responder essa sua questão?

Comment: Não há mal nenhum nisso @JhonatanDevss, para responder à tua questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @JhonatanDevss O sistema permite você mesmo responder a sua pergunta, existe até uma opção para isso quando você está criando uma pergunta.
Geralmente, o que as pessoas fazem é apenas trazer conteúdos para o site, e deixá-lo mais completo. 
Não posso afirmar se é o caso dele, mas isso acontece com bastante frequência.
Caso tenha alguma dúvida sobre esse tipo de coisa ou outra relacionada ao site, você pode utilizar o [Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) para e perguntar sobre o do site. Lá tempos usuários e moderadores respondendo esse tipo de dúvida, que é normal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basicamente é  a programação que estrutura a execução através de rotinas estanques que são chamadas conforme a necessidade. [Normalmente as chamamos de funções, mas não precisa ser exatamente essa forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101).

Normalmente essas rotinas possuem parâmetros para se comunicar com as outras partes do código e pode retornar algum valor, mas não é obrigatório, apesar de ficar confuso misturar tudo ou pouco poderoso não permitir nenhuma comunicação.

Certamente a definição disso não é "uma programação baseada em *procedures* (procedimentos)". Bom, até é, mas tem que tomar cuidado porque o procedimento é um mecanismo de rotina estanque. Um que é pouco usado na maioria das linguagens modernas de forma explícita. Claro que uma função que retorna nada (em geral `void`) não deixa de ser um procedimento. O termo procedural é usado como forma genérica.

Assim como [programação funcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101) não é "aquela que tem funções", até porque se fosse o caso quase toda linguagem seria funcional.

O paradigma procedural é secundário e se refere mais à organização do código como um todo, assim como também é a orientação a objeto.

O principal que difere o procedural do orientado a objeto é que o primeiro glorifica os procedimentos, o comportamento, e o segundo glorifica o objeto, o estado (curiosamente os escondendo).

> [...] a programação procedural é uma evolução da programação estruturada [...]

A programação estruturada se preocupa só com o fluxo do código e não a sua compartimentação.

> [...] programação procedural é algo que, até certo ponto, inevitável [...]

Não concordo que seja inevitável o uso do procedural. O imperativo é quase inevitável. Falo isso em [O que é paradigma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101).

> [...] às vezes utilizado como sinônimo de programação imperativa [...]

É usado erroneamente como sinônimo de imperativo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: vai um exemplo com código ?