# PHP Metodo Procedural ou orientação Objeto

Tags: php

- Qual das duas são seguras?
- Posso Procedural trabalhar somente na Procedural
- Prós e contra da Procedural

Comment: Poderia contextualizar? Estão vagas demais as perguntas, quase impossível de dizer qual é a forma certa.

Comment: estou iniciando um projeto pois sei pouco de orientação a objeto Quero saber se qual a diferença nos dois métodos de programação vantagens e desvantagens, estou atrás de opiniões e não de textos tirados em livros

Comment: Quase tudo na programação é procedural, até mesmo código OO é procedural. De uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195069/27190) a respeito dos termos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambas são seguras. A programação orientada a objetos, além te todas suas facilidades como herança, polimorfismo e entre outras, lhe ajuda a manter a lógica da programação bem aplicada. Seu código "passa a fazer parte do mundo real", onde suas classes serão tratadas como Entidades, seus métodos/funções serão tratados como Ações destas Entidades, seus atributos/propriedades serão como Qualidades destas Entidades. Por outro lado o código procedural é mais rápido para implementar um sistema simples com Crude único onde não há necessidade de tratamentos. Existem ainda frameworks como Laravel, CodeIgniter, Cake PHP entre outras que te auxiliam na programação orientada oa objetos além de dar muitas opções de código pronto para uso. Fica a critério apenas da necessidade o uso de cada uma delas. Espero ter ajudado. Abraço.