# Significado de "o código atuando sobre os dados" e "os dados controlando o acesso ao código"

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação, programação-estruturada

Esta é uma questão puramente teórica sobre programação.

Gostaria de saber através de um exemplo *simples* (resposta com complemento de figuras, desenhos, etc.), o significado de duas frases para dois tipos de linguagens de programação:

- **estruturada:** *"o código atuando sobre os dados"*
- **orientada a objetos:** *"os dados controlando o acesso ao código"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nem todo mundo concorda com isso, mas é só um modo de pensar que faz pouca diferença no final.

Não sei onde viu essa comparação, mas ela já começa errada. [Programação estrutura, ao contrário do que pode parecer é sobre o algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211768/101). E [a orientação a objeto é sobre a estrutura de dados, é sobre a organização do código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101). Então não faz muito sentido tentar contrapor essas duas ideias.

O mesmo vale para o [imperativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101), que faz um pouco mais sentido contrapor, mas não muito. Não faz sentido escolher um ou outro, eles são complementarem. A [orientação a objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101) é um [paradigma secundário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) (na verdade algumas pessoas consideram que orientação sequer é paradigma).

A "oposição" da orientação a objeto é a [programação procedural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195069/101).

Daí já se vê que muito se fala sobre o assunto sem muito conhecimento do que se trata de fato. Muito menos faz sentido separar linguagem em [estruturada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122430/101) ou orientada a objeto. Isso é simplesmente um conceito errado.

Quase todo tempo o código das pessoas são imperativos e com algum uso de orientação a objeto.

O que provavelmente está querendo dizer com essas frases é que o código mais imperativo puro você chama ações que vão agir sobre dados e o código com estilo orientado a objeto você pega o dado e chama uma ação em cima dele.

Imperativo procedural:

```
substring("abc", 3, 1)
```

Imperativo orientado a objeto:

```
"abc".substring(3, 1)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/OOSyntax.ptg).

Então acaba sendo apenas quem é invocado primeiro, o comportamento, ou o estado. Então no primeiro o código de `substring()` atuará sobre o texto `"abc"` (proceduralmente atua no objeto), enquanto que no segundo você tem o texto `"abc"` controlando o acesso ao código de `substring()` (o objeto chama o procedimento).

Fora ajudar um IDE fragmentar mais facilmente o que pode fazer com o dado, muda muito pouco e chega ser bobagem brigar mais por um ou outro estilo. A orientação a objeto tem algumas vantagens, assim como tem desvantagens também, em outras partes.

Essa facilidade chega ser até pior porque muitas pessoas acham que o fato de ser fácil achar os métodos que o objeto pode executar não lhe obriga estudar a documentação, e ela acaba fazendo códigos muito piores. Pior, por querer fazer o que está na moda de qualquer jeito ela acaba fazendo o que não entenda.

Pode ser útil:

- [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101)
- [PHP mistura códigos de orientação a objetos e linguagem procedural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101)
- [Quais são os pilares da programação orientada à objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215679/101)
- [O que é "Orientado a objeto" e quais outros métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101)

Comment: As frases estão contidas no livro "Java para inicnantes - 5ªed. - Herbert Schildt - editora Bookman - pág. 9". E, as duas frases estão escritas exatamente assim.

Comment: Ele é considerado um dos piores autores de livros do mercado.

Comment: Sendo um dos piores e na 5ª Edição, o mercado de livros da área anda bem mal então rsrs.

Comment: @Sam obrigado pela oportunidade de detalhar mais. É o que eu falo sempre, geralmente o leigo em algo é a pessoa menos capacitada para avaliar se algo é bom. Ela sempre é capaz de dizer o que ela gosta, o que ele viu de bonito, mas bom depende da pessoa ser qualificada naquilo. Daí vem o famoso https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect. As pessoas sempre acham que sabem mais do que realmente sabem. E se acham no direito de indicar produtos que elas não conseguem qualificá-lo corretamente, ...

Comment: ....portanto indicações de material de estudo só deveria ser considerada se vem de alguém comprovadamente muito qualificado, mas entramos em um dilema já que o leigo também não sabe qualificar sua fonte de indicação. As pessoas tendem a confiar em pessoas aleatórias na internet para tudo. Vale para a política, vale para decisões de consumo em geral, e chega valer até para alguém que deveria seguir um critério científico. Vale inclusive para a pessoa escolher no que vota ou escolhe respostas aqui no site.

Comment: Por isso costumamos dizer que a aceitação vale pouco, é a opção de alguém que claramente não entende do assunto, daí a  votação maior tende a expressar melhor a qualidade. Não é perfeito, é um pouco de generalização, mas funciona melhor como parâmetro. Um dos motivos de não aceitarmos indicação de livros e afins. As pessoas postarão e votarão em material **popular**, que é bem diferente de qualificado. O Schildt é um autor de prateleira forte, fez uma marca, se fortaleceu entre leigos e vira o círculo vicioso, leigos continuam indicando os livros dele, ...

Comment: ... e continuam sendo leigos acreditando em muita coisa errada publicada nesses livros (claro, também tem muita coisa certa) e essas pessoas passam a vida toda acreditando em coisas erradas que aprenderam. É muito comum as pessoas serem teimosas com a segunda fonte que recebem, então se ela aprendeu errado na primeira é complicado ela mudar de ideia depois. É comum as pessoas não procurarem uma fonte melhor, não tirar a prova e ficar com sua opinião em vez do fato. E sim, o mercado editorial de informática é composto de muito produto problemático.

Comment: O material na internet então nem se fala, quase tudo tem problemas, e geralmente são os sites mais populares. E assim as pessoas continuam cheias de buracos na aprendizagem acreditando em saci pererê. Acontece com todo mundo. Por isso é preciso manter a cabeça aberta e melhorar sempre. Desde que eu comecei postar aqui eu já melhorei o entendimento de muita coisa que antes eram falhas, especialmente sobre orientação a objeto, o assunto que provavelmente mais tem material falho, e quase certo que o assunto que as pessoas mais querem dominar e não chegam entender nem o básico do básico.

Comment: O motivo de eu responder aqui é que aprendo muito com a dúvidas dos outros. Vou colocar aqui alguns *links* sobre os livros dele: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/schildt.html, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7031/389 (veja mais na mesma página), e aqui tem uma tentativa de defesa, mas a leitura cuidadosa do texto mostra como esses livros podem destruir a cabecinha das pessoas e torná-las crentes: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-herbert-schildt-C-a-poor-book.E aidna https://www.quora.com/Why-do-many-programmers-dislike-Herbert-Schildts-books, ...

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente a sua posição, e até apoio. Acho que nem sempre o que se vende por aí é o melhor. Acredito que tem muito da questão de marketing, o que vale é o $ vindo. Se o cara chegou na 5ª edição não lhe garante qualidade, mas em número de vendas, não importa se o material é bom ou não, mas é "engolido" por uma massa leiga que acha que é bom. Dou mt credibilidade ao que vc fala pq sei que que entende do assunto. Eu mesmo já comprei livros que depois de um tempo vi que não passava de sensacionalismo e marketing sazonal, e vi que tudo aquilo era bobeira...

Comment: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/CS/BadBooksC+C++.html ( O Jamsa era muito ruim, mas parece que ele desapareceu, tinha um autores nacional tb que era desse nível, vendia horrores, tem defensores até hj a despeito da quantidade de erros que ele colocava nos seus livros, completo relaxo), https://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html, https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/143wjc/whats_wrong_with_herbert_schildts_books_on_java/, http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bullschildt.html (olha a que ponto chegamos, tem um termo sobre os livros dele), e a lista vai longe

Comment: Eu tenho um monte de porcaria na minha estante (ou tinha) algumas estou descobrindo o problema mais recentemente. Claro todos os livros tem coisas boas, ensina mais que desensina, mas o estrago que eles fazem é muito grande. Hoje leio tudo com um pé atrás, vou procurar outras fontes, ver se faz sentido. Mesmo assim ainda caio em armadilhas. Todo mundo cai, até gente muito consagrada. Por isso tem tanta gente comprando ideias ruins em dev que só servem pra vender livro, curso, consultoria, ferramenta auxiliar, serviço desnecessário.

Comment: Vc falou, tá falado rs...  E oBg tb!