# Uso do método constructor em JS

Tags: javascript, construtor

Eu aprendi que ao criar uma função com métodos inseridos diretamente dentro dela vai criar um acúmulo desnecessário de memória, pois toda vez que a classe for instanciada cada instância teria seu próprio método ocupando um espaço diferente na memória.

Para resolver isso poderíamos acessar a propriedade `prototype` da função e colocar os métodos diretamente lá; contudo de forma automática toda função tem um `prototype` com uma propriedade `constructor` que aponta diretamente para a função e se eu criar um `prototype` por fora eu irei sobrescrever o `prototype` da função e deixar ela sem a propriedade `constructor`.

Por isso eu adicionei esta propriedade diretamente no `prototype` criado manualmente.

A minha pergunta é qual a diferença da função sem a propriedade `constructor`, pois aparentemente os dois códigos funcionaram de forma semelhante?

> Fonte do código: O Programador Objetivo.

Código com `constructor`:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype = {
    constructor: Person,
    sayName: function (){
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    toString: function(){
        return "[Person" + this.name + "]";
    }
}
```

Código sem `constructor`:

```
function Person2(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person2.prototype = {
    sayName: function (){
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    toString: function(){
        return "[Person" + this.name + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ...estou aprendendo classes em JavaScript e estou quase perdendo a
> cabeça com uma coisa que parece ser bem simples na Programação
> Orientada a Objetos...

Caso o leitor tenha dúvidas a respeito de JavaScript ser ou não uma Linguagem de Paradigma Orientado a Objetos, ou ainda não tenha esse conceito bem sedimentado, ou ainda algum conceito explicado abaixo pareça estranho sugiro a leitura:

- [O que é Paradigma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/137387)
- [JavaScript é uma linguagem Orientada a Objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141645/137387)
- [Qual é o paradigma de programação usado pelo JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126886/137387)
- [O que é "Orientado a objeto" e quais outros métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/137387)
- [POO é igual em todas as linguagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213951/137387)
- [O que é Protótipo JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/137387)
- [Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%C3%B3tipos-em-javascript)

> ...toda função tem um prototype com uma propriedade constructor que
> aponta diretamente para a função e se eu criar um prototype por fora
> eu irei sobrescrever o prototype da função e deixar ela sem a
> propriedade constructor, por isso eu adicionei esta propriedade
> diretamente no prototype criado manualmente...

Deve ser esclarecido que o valor da propriedade [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) de uma instancia de um [objeto Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) é utilizada quando a função é usada como um constructor com o operador [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), o valor dessa propriedade `prototype` se tornará o protótipo de objeto instanciado.

[Protótipo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) é o mecanismo pelo qual os objetos JavaScript herdam recursos uns dos outros e a propriedade de um objeto que aponta para seu protótipo não é chamada `prototype`.
Não existe uma propriedade padrão para acessar protótipos, por enquanto na prática todos os navegadores utilizam a propriedade [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). Porém segundo [o padrão ECMA a propriedade `__proto__` tornou-se obsoleta](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) e deve ser evitada.
Veja [tabela de compatibilidade da propriedade `__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#compatibilidade_com_navegadores) que no momento em que escrevo essa resposta o engine JS Deno já não suporta mais a propriedade `__proto__`.

A forma padrão de acessar o protótipo de um objeto é:

- fazer a leitura do protótipo com o método estático  [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).
- fazer a sobrescrição do protótipo com o método [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

  > **Atenção:** alterar o protótipo dessa forma pode sobrescrever otimizações que engines JS produzem, podendo trazer prejuízos quanto ao tempo de acesso as propriedades do objeto cujo protótipo foi modificado.

Quando a função é chamada como um constructor junto da da palavra chave `new` acontecerá a [seguinte sequencia de ações](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description):

1. Cria um objeto JavaScript simples e em branco. Por conveniência, chamaremos de `newInstance`, e aqui propriedade interna que aponta para o protótipo dum objeto que somente **aqui na explicação** será chamada `[[protótipo]]`.
2. Aponta o`[[protótipo]]` de `newInstance` para a propriedade `prototype` da função construtora, se `prototype` for um `Object`. Caso contrário, no caso de um tipo primitivo, `newInstance` permanece como um objeto simples com `Object.prototype` com seu `[[protótipo]]`.
3. Executa a função construtora com os argumentos fornecidos, vinculando `this` ao contexto de `newInstance` fazendo todas as referências a `this` na função construtora agora se referem a `newInstance`.
   4.Se a função construtora retornar um valor não primitivo , esse valor de retorno se tornará o resultado de toda a expressão `new`. Caso contrário, se a função construtora não retornar nada ou retornar um primitivo, será retornado `newInstance`.
   Normalmente, os construtores não retornam um valor, mas podem optar por fazê-lo para substituir o processo normal de criação de objetos.

Tendo isso esclarecido, voltando a questão

> ...se eu criar um prototype por fora eu irei sobrescrever o prototype da função e deixar ela sem a propriedade constructor?

**NÃO!** Como já foi explicado, no processo de instanciação de objetos com a palavra chave `new`, a propriedade `prototype` da função construtora só será adicionada a cadeia de protótipos do objeto instanciado após esse ter sido criado, e portanto, o constructor usado será a própria função construtora e **NESSE CASO** o constructor fornecido com o protótipo, "criado por fora", não será utilizado. Veja o exemplo:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

const p1 = Object.getPrototypeOf(Person);


Person.prototype = {
  constructor: Person,
  sayName: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  },
  toString: function() {
    return "[Person" + this.name + "]";
  }
}

const p2 = Object.getPrototypeOf(Person);
console.log(p1 === p2); ///true - a propriedade Function.prototype só será usada na cadeia de prótótipos da instância apósa instanciação.

const p3 = Object.getPrototypeOf(new Person("Augusto"));
console.log(p1 === p3); ///false - A função Person() continua com sua cadeia cadeia de protótipos inalterada enquanto as instancias de Person() receberão Person.prototype em sua cadeia de protótipos
```

O que já fornece embasamento para pergunta principal.

> Qual a diferença da função sem a propriedade constructor, pois aparentemente os dois códigos funcionaram de forma semelhante?

Sim, aparentemente os dois códigos funcionaram de forma semelhante. Mas avaliar as coisas de forma aparente nem sempre é suficiente.
A principal diferença é maneira como será conferido valor a propriedade [`Object.prototype.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor), propriedade essa que retorna uma referência à função construtora que "criou" a instância.

No exemplo apresentado na pergunta fica pouco evidente porém no exemplo abaixo é possível deixar mais claro. Serão criados alguns objetos:

- Duas funções verbosas `Foo()` e `Bar()`, que se anunciam no console quando chamadas, que serão usadas como funções construtoras.
- `foo` que é instância de `Foo()`.
- `foo2` que também é instância de `Foo()`, porém é criado após alteração no protótipo de `Foo()` alterando constructor para `Bar()`.
- Usando a expressão `new foo.constructor();` serão criado dois objetos por derivação de `foo`, lembrando que [javascript não tem realmente o conceito de classe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) é só açúcar sintático da linguagem para as heranças baseadas nos protótipos.
- Através da expressão `new foo2.constructor();` será criado um objeto por derivação de `foo2`.

```js
function Foo() {
  console.log("Sou Foo");
}

function Bar() {
  console.log("Sou Bar");
}

const foo = new Foo()  /// Sou Foo
new foo.constructor(); /// Sou Foo  

Foo.prototype = {
  constructor: Bar
}

new foo.constructor();  /// Sou Foo 

const foo2 = new Foo()  /// Sou Foo - não há substituição do constructor.
new foo2.constructor(); /// Sou Bar - Aqui há substituição do constructor.
```

Veja que no exemplo acima que a definição do constructor no protótipo irá afetar a propriedade `Object.prototype.constructor`

Também serão afetados o funcionamento do operador [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) que testa se a a função construtora aparece em algum lugar na cadeia de protótipos de um objeto.

```js
function Foo() {
  console.log("Sou Foo");
}

function Bar() {
  console.log("Sou Bar");
}

const foo1 = new Foo()              /// Sou Foo
 

Foo.prototype = {
  constructor: Bar
}

const foo2 = new Foo();             /// Sou Foo

const foo3= new foo1.constructor(); /// Sou Foo
const foo4= new foo2.constructor(); /// Sou Bar

console.log(foo1 instanceof Foo);  // false
console.log(foo2 instanceof Foo);  // true
console.log(foo3 instanceof Foo);  // true
console.log(foo4 instanceof Foo);  // false

console.log(foo1 instanceof Bar);  // false
console.log(foo2 instanceof Bar);  // false
console.log(foo3 instanceof Bar);  // false
console.log(foo4 instanceof Bar);  // true
```

O mesmo se dá com código reflexivo:

```js
function Foo() {
  console.log("Sou Foo");
}

function Bar() {
  console.log("Sou Bar");
}

Foo.prototype = {
  constructor: Bar
}

const foo1 = new Foo();                               /// Sou Foo
const foo2 = Reflect.construct(foo1.constructor, []); /// Sou Bar
const foo3 = Object.create(Foo.prototype);            /// 

console.log(foo1 instanceof Foo);  // true
console.log(foo2 instanceof Foo);  // false
console.log(foo3 instanceof Foo);  // true

console.log(foo1 instanceof Bar);  // false
console.log(foo2 instanceof Bar);  // true
console.log(foo3 instanceof Bar);  // false
```

Material de consulta:

- [Constructors Considered Mildly Confusing](https://zeekat.nl/articles/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html) sugerido pelo usuário
  [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo)
- [MDN Webdocs - Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)
- [MDN Webdocs - Object.prototype.**proto**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)
- [MDN Webdocs - Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)
- [MDN Webdocs - Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)
- [MDN Webdocs - Function: prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype)
- [MDN Webdocs - Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)
- [MDN Webdocs - Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)
- [MDN Webdocs - Operator new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: +1...lá se foi o almoço...

Comment: @CmteCardeal. Acabei de comer um espetinho que valeu pelo almoço e lanche da tarde. :D