# Por que JavaScript permite usar variáveis sem declarar?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, declaração-de-variável, escopo-de-variáveis

Estava fazendo um teste no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sganc85c/), com o código abaixo. Nele eu não declarei a variável `i`, mas mesmo assim, consigo usá-la normalmente.

Isso é intencional ou é uma falha? Então, eu posso simplesmente sair usando variáveis sem declarar, no estilo Python?

Também percebi que posso usar a variável em qualquer lugar do código, obviamente, isso faz sentido porque como ela não está declarada, não tem escopo. Mas essa "possibilidade" é justamente pra podermos criar variáveis de "escopo global"?

```js
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    document.write(i + '<br>');
}

i = 'asdasd';

document.write(i);
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Quando se deve usar var no javascript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2513/quando-se-deve-usar-var-no-javascript)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Se é intencional ou é falha há controvérsias :) Bom, pode-se dizer que é intencional. Como toda "boa" [linguagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101), em todos os sentidos, como uma [linguagem de *script*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17082/101) deve ser, ela deve facilitar ao máximo a vida do programador fazer coisas rápidas sem cerimônia. Então escolheu-se não exigir a declaração.

Se não declarar a variável terá [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) global, o que não é ideal, e assumirá o melhor valor que puder.

No exemplo não há uma declaração explícita, mas a variável não deixa de ser declarada de forma automática. Ela continua sendo global e um valor está atribuído.

Eu vejo o critério de ser global mais como acidente de algo mal pensado, mas não posso afirmar isso. Mesmo sendo útil ter algo global seria preferível ter uma declaração explícita que fosse assim. Pelo menos o padrão deveria ser local.

Pra ficar bom mesmo criaram o [`let`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101), afinal JS não quer mais ser uma linguagem de *script*. Aconselho ler lá para entender melhor sobre escopos em JS.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Importante ter citado sobre o `let`. Eu não conhecia. Creio que seria o mais viável ao caso do `for`.

Comment: Se puder usar, costuma ser melhor, porque o `var` é manco também.

Answer (score 11):

Quando você deixa de utilizar o `var` numa declaração de uma variável, você está declarando ela no contexto global, independentize do escopo em que você a declarou.

Veja:

```js
function call_me_baby() {
    a = 1;
    var b = 2;
}


call_me_baby();

console.log(typeof(a), typeof(b));
```

Observe que a variável `a` foi "enviada" para o escopo global. Já a variável `b` ficou limitada ao escopo de `call_me_baby`.

Quando você faz uma declaração de uma variável sem o uso do `var`, poderíamos dizer que é o equivalente a fazer a atribuição diretamente no objeto `window`.

Veja:

```
call_me_baby() {
    window.a = 1;
}
```

No caso específico do `for`, aconteceria a mesma coisa se você não usasse `var` para declarar a variável. A variável `i` seria definida implicitamente no escopo global, independente do escopo em que o `for` é invocado.

Você pode inclusive usar o `var` no `for` de duas formas:

```
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}
```

Ou

```
 for  (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}
```

É importante notar que a não declaração do `i` poderia ocasionar problemas de colisão de nomes e declarações indevidas.

Outra nota importante é que com o uso de `"use strict"`, a falta do `var` na declaração de `i` poderia gerar um erro.

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";
  a = 1;
 })();
```

Veja mais em:

- [Quando se deve usar var no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2513/quando-se-deve-usar-var-no-javascript/2517#2517)

Answer (score 6):

A linguagem não é perfeita :) Poder fazer atribuições de valor a variáveis não declaradas é uma falha da linguagem que tem tipagem fraca. Digo falha porque gera sobre-escrições de variáveis sem darmos conta e gera erros dificeis de encontrar.

Exemplo:

```js
(function(c) {
    console.log(a); // undefined
    try {
        console.log(b); // vai dar erro
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Erro!'); // erro: ReferenceError: b is not defined
    }
    var a = 10;
    console.log(a); // 10
    b = 10;
    console.log(b); // 10
    console.log(c); // undefined
})();
console.log('No escopo global:')
console.log(typeof a, typeof b, typeof c); // b dá number!, as outras estão undefined
```

Neste exemplo em cima a variável `b` e `c` não são declaradas explicitamente. `b` é exportado para o escopo global, o que é perigoso e pode gerar bugs feios. `c` é gerado pela função, como parametro. De certa maneira é declarada, mas não explicitamente. Isto gera erros de interpretação do código e deve ser evitado, pois podemos pensar que chamar a função sem passar um valor como argumento é bug.

Uma vêz que há muito código que confia neste comportamento (errado) não é pacífico mudar esse comportamento.

#### Como evitar isto?

A melhor maneira de evitar esse tipo de problemas é usar o [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). O *strict mode* é um comando que faz um código correr em modo mais controlado. Ele exige que algumas regras importantes sejam cumpridas, uma delas essa mesma que falas na pergunta. Ou seja: em *strict mode* dar valores a variáveis não declaradas dá erro!

```js
function normal() {
    a = 10;
}
normal();
console.log(typeof a); // number


function strict() {
    "use strict";
    b = 10; // o código pára aqui pois isto gera um erro
}
strict();
console.log(typeof b);
```